# Excel VBA, Simple "For Each" macro shift the range

Tags: excel, vba, foreach

I'm trying to run a really simple code to simulate F2+Enter on each cells in a range.

I know, I should use something else, but in my case nothing else work!

Any range I put in the code, the macro strat at the end of the range and do the number of cells included in my range!!!

I've try with simple range or dynamic range, same thing.

With the code below, it will start at AC100 and stop at AC200.

```
Dim Rng As Variant, Cell As Range

Set Rng = Range("AC1:AC100")
For Each Cell In Rng.Cells
    Cell.Select
    SendKeys "{F2}", True
    SendKeys "{ENTER}", True
Next Cell
```

Pretty sure it's a little detail that I've misted, but I can't see what.

Thanks!

Comment: What is causing the need to do this?

Comment: @ScottCraner IME that would be a date column pulled from some SQL data source, that Excel isn't understanding as a date - F2+Enter does work for this, ...but a much better alternative is to simply add a helper column with a `DATEVALUE` function that converts the `String` date into an actual `Date`. Or, use PowerQuery / Get & Transform to pull the data.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I was thinking they were formulas that are not calculating which the F2-Enter will force a recalc.  In which case checking to make sure the calcs are set to automatic or hitting F9 would do the same.

Comment: @ScottCraner that's another possibility indeed!

Comment: Thanks, the 'application.sendkeys' work great!

Comment: And for the 'why', it's really a SQL query thing, but not a date. It's a RFT field that came with all the code. I've try changing the format or doing some 'activate', but F2+enter is the only one that work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim Rng As Variant, Cell As Range

    Set Rng = Range("AC1:AC100")
    For Each Cell In Rng.Cells
        Cell.Select
        Application.SendKeys "{F2}"
        Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
        DoEvents
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

**NOTE:**

We specify `Application` to prevent `SendKeys` from going to the *VBE*
The `DoEvents` prevents he `SendKeys` from "piling-up"

Comment: Side note: OP might want to toggle `Application.EnableEvents` off before & back on after that loop, to avoid triggering worksheet events 99 times (assuming the intent isn't to trigger such events in the first place).

Comment: Other side note: Parameterless `Range.Cells` call is entirely superfluous ;-)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon  Thank you for the comments.